# React Native - can't request location permissions using PermissionsAndroid

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to request runtime location permissions but my promise keeps throwing this exception:

"Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity"

My code look like this:

```
  PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
  .then((preGranted) => {
    console.log('pre-granted', preGranted)
    if (!preGranted) {
      PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        { 'title': 'Enable location', 'message': 'Boss said so..' }
      )
      .then((granted) => {
        if (granted) {
          console.log('GRANTED AFTER ASKING:', granted)
          debugger
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

In my manifest i have:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Has anyone come across that message? What is PermissionAwareActivity im having trouble finding anything about it online.

Comment: There is nothing named `PermissionsAndroid` in the Android SDK. If you are using some library, perhaps that library has `PermissionAwareActivity`.

Comment: I put react-native in the tags, but didn't specify in my question. sry, my bad.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**Note: This answer is based on Java instead of Reactive native. Please refer other answers for a React native specific solution**

> What is PermissionAwareActivity

PermissionAwareActivity is an interface which helps you to fetch run time permissions. You have to implement these methods in your own activity.

```
  public interface PermissionAwareActivity {

  int checkPermission(String permission, int pid, int uid);


  int checkSelfPermission(String permission);

  boolean shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(String permission);

  void requestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode, PermissionListener listener);
}
```

Comment: this should not be the approved answer as it is an android specific answer and not for react native

Comment: Exactly, hey author, can you explain on what basis you approved this answer?

Comment: This answer does not provide solution for react native

Answer (score 2):

you should implements PermissionAwareActivity in your activity,
and define the Callback && PermissionListener .

```
public class ReactNativeIndexActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler,PermissionAwareActivity {
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    private @Nullable   Callback mPermissionsCallback;
    private @Nullable PermissionListener mPermissionListener;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ......
}

  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this);
        }
        if (mPermissionsCallback != null) {
            mPermissionsCallback.invoke();
            mPermissionsCallback = null;
        }
    }

 @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void requestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode, PermissionListener listener) {
        mPermissionListener = listener;
        requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {
        mPermissionsCallback = new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(Object... args) {
                if (mPermissionListener != null && mPermissionListener.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)) {
                    mPermissionListener = null;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`PermissionAwareActivity` is an interface in a third party library.

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation

It is not part of the standard Android SDK.

Instructions for requesting runtime permissions using the standard SDK can be found in the documentation.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html